# Is it a good idea to make div act as a table using CSS properties like display: table or should I use table element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I know table rendering is slow.. My question is, does using div instead of table tag make any difference in rendering?

If you have any reason for your answer, please share.It would be really helpful for me.

Comment: You should simply use the element that makes sense semantically. You have tabular data? Use `table`. You need a generic grouping/structuring element? `div` is probably the right choice. As for performance, I don't know.

Comment: Without seeing a [mcve] of your code, it's hard to give you performance advice.

Comment: what is the difference between, creating a div and setting css properties like display:table,display:table-row.. so on, and, using table tag.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to provide you any code samples.. But let me explain how my work is going to be. I am going to have series of rows and columns and I am going to fill them with values. Think of an microsoft excel. I would like to do such tables and pass values to them. The values can be either number or string @evolutionxbox

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply. I really want to know performance difference. Any how thanks.@domdom

Comment: Avoid premature optimisation and use the element that is best suited to what you are trying to do. Since you mentioned excel, it sounds like you have tabular data, so use `table`. Any performance difference will only be noticeable for a very large table. Probably so large that you will probably have other UI/UX issues to solve at that point. My gut tells me in your instance a table should be more performant. How many table cells are we talking here?

Answer (score 0):

#### There is no unique answer to this question, it really dependes on what you are going to to with this table tag

The thing is, you must (well, should) only use the `<table>` tag for tabular data. It was and sometimes still is being abused for layout purposes, which is extremely bad practice for a variety of reasons, and CSS is the preferred technology to use there.

I suggest you start looking from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless_web_design) for information about **Tableless Layout**.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your scenario, if its more like an excel sheet structure and a simple screen layout, 'table' tag should be preferable. But, with div and css layout, there is a lot more flexibility in your table design, but on the other side you will have a lot of css manipulations.
With div layout, each div will render one by one. With 'table' tag , table would be displayed when completely loaded. 
With css layout, you might also have to consider how your css changes work in different browsers(in case you are using old IE versions).